# How I can count how many times my component rendered in a react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following React component,

```js
import React, {useState} from "react"

export default function App(){
  const [state, setState] = useState(0);
  return <>
    <button onClick={() => setState(state + 3)}>Click to increment</button>
    {state}
  </>
}
```

How will be able to display the number of times my component has rendered!
Thanks!

Comment: use useRef hook

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`renderCount.current` represents the render count for your component. You can use the following code, but for react 18, the first time renderCount.current will be equal to 2, and then will increment by one. If you want the first time renderCound.current to be 1, use react 17
Thanks!

```js
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState(0);
  const renderCount = useRef(0);
  useEffect(() => {
    renderCount.current = renderCount.current + 1;
  });

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => setState(state + 3)}>Click to increment</button>
      {state}
      {renderCount.current}
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Store a counter outside the component. Increment it each time the component renders.

```
let renderCount = 0;

export default function App(){
  const [state, setState] = useState(0);
  renderCount++;
  return <>
    <button onClick={() => setState(state + 3)}>Click to increment</button>
    {state}
    <p>This component has rendered {renderCount} times.</p>
  </>
}
```

Note that sometimes a component might be rendered extra times (e.g. for [Strict Mode](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html) tests).

Comment: Isn't there any way I can keep all the code inside the functional component!

Comment: I suppose you could use a reference, but it would add a lot of complexity and count renders of an instance of a component instead of renders of a component.

Answer (score 1):

i saw in other post and option to just add

> console.count('counter')

with in your code  and then each time the component renders it will update the counter